# Nginx different service on subroute

Tags: django, nginx, routes, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have 2 Django apps running on 8080 and 8081 ports. I use gunicorn and NGINX to serve them.

Currently I have only the app on port 8080 added to NGINX, the config in sites-enabled (part of it) looks like that:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Now I need to add there the second app, which is on port 8081, but so that it is served on `/second_app` route. So I see it like this:

```
/           -> 127.0.0.1:8080
/second_app -> 127.0.0.1:8081
```

However, when I do the second location to be `/second_app` it doesn't work, I think these two routes conflict and as long as the first on is wider it "consumes" the request.

Also I think it is worth mentioning that the "8080 app" doesn't have any route that starts with `/second_app`, so it cannot conflict with "8081 app".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your new server more specific regex first in file and use proper [block syntax](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#location-block-syntax)

```
 location ^~ /second_app {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 }
```